# Swift - Why does a 'while' statement after a 'do' statement cause compiler error?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

If I try to enter a `while` loop right after a `do` statement like this:

```swift
do {
   print("you can change your face, but can't change your mind.")
}

while true {
   print("no matter what do you do!")
}
```

compiler thinks that the `while` is a part of `do` statement and gives this error.

```sh
'do-while' statement is not allowed; use 'repeat-while' instead.
```

However, if I add a semicolon `;` after the `do` statement, then it compiles fine.

But I thought the empty-line between `do` and `while` statements would make my intention clear to the compiler, that I'm starting a new `while` statement independently from the previous `do` statement. And since `do-while` is not supported by the language, there wouldn't be an ambiguity here.

Do you have an idea why the compiler behaves this way?

Comment: An empty line does not automatically mean that the next row is a new statement, most of the time it works anyway but when the compiler is in doubt of what you mean you need to use a ;. Having `return 5 \n +5` at the end of a function will not generate a syntax error, instead the function will return 10.

Comment: Empty line is not considered to be a statement separator when the syntax remains incomplete. Try the following in 3 lines with a blank line between 1 and + .`let a = 1

+ 2`. This could also be because of initial versions of Swift Supporting `do-while` that is possibly why the compiler is prompting a fix

Comment: Compiles fine with XCode 13.3/Swift 5.6 - seems the compiler bug was fixed meanwhile.